# Open source encryption library pose export compliance

Tags: software, open-source-software, encryption, export

I am developing an app which will encrypt users files , photos etc. I use the open source library RNCryptor to do the operation . Does this make my app require export compliance ? . Does the export compliance also be implied if the app is developed outside us by a non us citizen Or a non us firm ?.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, I don't know if you're familiar with US law, but software that includes encryption capabilities is covered by weapons-export regulations (yes, seriously).  This is very much a question of law, not a question of open-sourceness.

Comment: I'm familiar with US laws; and crypto, too, as I have a rep of 20K+ on Stack Overflow under as my other SE account. Many "drive-by" questions about open source end up on this stack, and they are best moved to Open Source SE where there are people much more familiar with the IT world and many times there are already answers.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch okay, but that doesn't mean it's off-topic here, either.  I'd be very interested in a full treatment of the whole "encryption and weapon export regulations" thing.

Comment: Write an answer, and if the community sees it as valuable, the question may not be closed.

Comment: I'd write an answer, but even after hours of research, the answer I have is "I don't know".  There's a reason why all the major open-source encryption software is developed in Europe.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch and others, just as a heads up, [opensource.se] should mostly be used for questions about the legal nature of open source software. In this case, the open source library used is almost tangential to the question, and the question is better suited to receive answers from this site rather than Open Source. That's why I sent this back. It's a perfectly on-topic question for this site, voting to reopen.

Comment: Exported from where? Exported how? For example, from the United States by making it available to anyone through the Android and/or Apple stores? Or only by paying customers with a contract? Or only to North Korea? Export laws depend on details like these, omitting them will get you a possibly worthless answer.